# How to load my own Image data with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an image set which has **300,000** images in it. There are **10000 categories** and **30 images per category**. Each image file name is like `01_flower.png, 02_flower.png, 01_cat.png ...`.

The question is:

1. How to load these images with tensorflow.
2. How to encode testing image tag to one hot vector.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell where exactly your Problems start.

> To get you started, there are [multiple ways](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) to load data into a
>   TensorFlow program:

- Feeding: Python code provides the data when running each step.
- Reading from files: an input pipeline reads the data from files at the beginning of a TensorFlow graph.
- Preloaded data: a constant or variable in the TensorFlow graph holds all the data (for small data sets).

A small Code example could look like that:

```
with tf.Session():
  input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  classifier = ...
  print(classifier.eval(feed_dict={input: your_data}))
```